# set spring.jpa.open-in-view=false,then query.unwrap(NativeQueryImpl.class) gives exception,why?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My SpringBoot version is 2.0.8.RELEASE. 
hibernate version is 5.2.17.Final

When I set the spring jpa configuration of open-in-view to false,then I query database by sql,it give me exception:

```
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy234 cannot be cast to org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl
```

Java Code:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> doSqlQuery(String sql, Map<String,Object> parameters) {
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
        setQueryParameters(query, parameters);
        return query.unwrap(NativeQueryImpl.class)
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP).list();
    }
```

Of course I can use the 'SQLQuery.class' to replace 'NativeQueryImpl.class',but it  was deprecated in hibernate

Comment: Don't unwrap to `NativeQueryImpl` (requesting a specific class is generally a bad idea). Instead use the hibernate `Query` interface for the `unwrap` method.

Comment: but I want to return List<Map> , how can I dont't unwrap to NativeQueryImpl  and achieve it

Comment: The only thing you want to do is set the result transformer. That is also available on the hibernate `Query` interface. Generally programming to concrete implementations is a bad idea, use interfaces.